# Select all function in sales>orders in Magento 1.6.1.0

Tags: magento, configuration

I have recently upgraded to Magento 1.6.1.0 from 1.3 and have just noticed that there is no longer a select all function in the order screen just select visable, does anyone know if there is a setting somewhere to turn this on and off I have looked everywhere and cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the latest stable version of magento is already in 1.7 so please upgrade to that as it has a couple of important bug/security fixes

For the select all option you have to overwrite the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid class in either a module or in your local code.

In the _prepareMassaction() method there is a line:

```
$this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);
```

set this to true and you have your select all.

Comment: Bas Tuijnman thank you very much, i will give this a try, never like editing core code but will have to to create this option. Does it have any affect whatsoever on anything else in the magento installation? Yes I have noticed a fair few bugs especially not being able to use Paypal as all orders come through as suspected fraud. Thanks again.

Comment: What you can do is create a new model which extends the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid class and override the _prepareMassaction() method by doing setUseSelectAll(false); and then executing the parent method by doing: parent::_prepareMassaction()

Comment: your first answer worked great I wil just revert back to the orginal grid file once I have completed the move of all email address. Thanks again.